# PHP controlling a finger print device

Tags: java, php

I have to control access to a system based on fingerprint recognition in `PHP`.
But I do not know what would be the best approach to do this...

I was searching for a device and software, and maybe this will the one I'll use:

[U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader digital persona](http://www.digitalpersona.com/Biometrics/Hardware-Products/U-are-U-4500-Reader/4500-Reader/)

This software use somekind of SDK, so java must be used, Is there a way to make a bridge between `php` and `java?`.

I am not expert in java web services, but if this is the only way, How to control fingerprint?

Does the device returns an `image`, or a `md5 string`, or How does it work, how to read this in php?

What is your experience in this kind of thing...

Comment: Have you downloaded the SDK yet? Does it come with documentation?

Comment: Well, I don't understand it at all, it has a `setup.sh`. Let me study it, But do you know How to make a bridge between `java` and `php`?

Comment: As for the specific operation of your chosen device you should consult the vendor. Typically you would just invoke an external tool to handle the verification `tf-tool --verify` instead of reimplementing the whole fingerprint recognition in PHP. In PHP! But if you really want the complexity of managing this yourself over a Java bridge: http://php.net/java

Comment: So the device handles md5 strings, or something, and then I exec a single command to verify it?, is this the way it works?.

Comment: Have you even tried to google java + php? Or, for instance, [searched the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php)?

Comment: have you done with project or have you find solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another dimension to this, too.

When you say "PHP", I imagine you're probably talking HTTP web server/client web browser interaction (with PHP on the server).

The Digital Persona (DP) device, however, is usually over on the client.

I've actually used Digital Persona (probably a different device and a different SDK than yours), but the principle is probably similar.  You plug the device into the PC's USB port, and the DP SDK controls the device, scans the thumbprint, compares it to other fingerprint images you've "registered" (in a database, a set of image files, whatever), and reports back whether or not there's a match.  This all occurs on the CLIENT side.

SUGGESTION:
Your best bet might be:

1) Code your server side stuff in PHP, as you're doing now

2) Code your DP interaction as a JAVA APPLET

3) You DON'T necessarily need to "call Java from PHP" (or vice versa).  Instead, all you need to do is:

- invoke the applet from the PHP pages you serve, and
- Have the applet communicate with the web server

Here's one example of how you might approach this:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010023

Answer (score 3):

What I believe as procedure to be done is:

1. Create a folder for storing fingerprints of authorised users;
2. When a fingerprint is inserted to login,
3. Retrieve the stored fingerprint of the user using php code $a;
4. Change the fingerprint of the current user into a php code $b;
5. Compare the two codes $a and $b
6. If `$a != $b` then
7. Give error msg,
8. If `$a == $b` then allow entry into system.

You may work on with me to achieve this in php as java is Greek to me.

Thank you.