# Integrating Biometric FingerPrint to PHP code

Tags: php, biometrics

:) I have a big problem. I just bought a biometric device (DigitalPersona Fingerprint Recognition Sytem), and my problem is, it does not support PHP. Are there some alternative ways, so that I can still use my hardware device? If I won't be able to use the device, it's just like I throw my P5,000.00. :'( Help please.

Comment: And why didnt you worry and research about that before paying `P5,000.00`?

Comment: I knew it, it was my fault. That's why I'm asking for suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464088/php-controlling-a-finger-print-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every biometric device stores info into its local database in the form of xml or flat files. And that biometric will be part of network so via its ip addresss you can read info. I worked with some biometric and humidity sensors and fire alrams uaing php